# How can i set the location of an axis label in terms of locations on said axis?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I would like to move my axis label `Number of States` to the left, so that it is actually over the numbers i have. Other similar questions/answers have suggested using `labelpad`, but this shifts the text up or down, not left/right. How can i move my title to the right?

i've also tried the `horizontalalignment` kwarg, which a. seems to have the `right` and `left` alignments reversed, and also does not move the title far enough, nor offer any actual control on where exactly it goes.

i see that i can set the `_x` and `_y` properties of the `Text` instance, using `set_[xy]()`, but it seems a bit hacky. Is there a convenient way i can set the location of hte title relative to a value on the xaxis?

[image]

Comment: does `plt.title(loc='left')` work?

Answer (score 2):

You can grap the title object and set its respective position property to whatever you like.
A simple example could be:

```py
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot([1,2,3])
ti=plt.title('foo')
ti.set_position((0.2,1))
```

which creates a plot like
[image]
Note that the position is set in relative coordinates.

The position argument suggested by @ThePredator (loc : {‘center’, ‘left’, ‘right’}, see [docs](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html?highlight=title#matplotlib.pyplot.title) also works in a similar fashion.

### Update

To set the position of the text in the data coordinate system instead of the axis coordinates, a simple transformation can be used. For details have a look at the [Transformation Documentation](http://matplotlib.org/users/transforms_tutorial.html). A minimal example could look like:

```
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
f,ax = plt.subplots(1)
ax.plot([1,2,3])
ti=ax.set_title('foo')
ti.set_position(ax.transLimits.transform((0.5,3)))
```

This places the title centered at (0.5, 3) as shown in the following plot
[image]

Comment: `.set_position` jsut sets both `_x` and `_y` at the same time, it doesn't let me set it directly relative to the poitn on the axis. I guess i'd need to convert from the plot point to the coords of the figure coordinates.

Comment: @will sorry I somehow missed the final paragraph of your question. I've updated my answer to add a data2axes transformation.

Comment: I haven't had a chance to try this out yet, but it presumably lets me use coords outside of the actual plotting area, correct?

Comment: Yes it's possible to use coords outside the plotting area, however depending on your backend the title will be visible or not. The IPython inline backend is rather tolerable and will increase the size of the image automatically. this is not true for other backends.